# how to add dynamic content to the primeng overlaypanel in angular project?

Tags: angular, lazy-loading, primeng

I want to display content on primeng overlaypanel dynamically. content will be loaded from the api. I need to display those content in the overlaypanel when I open it. Can anyone explain it how to do this in angular.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what your data looks like but the idea is this :

TS :

```
public data;

@ViewChild(OverlayPanel)
private overlayPanel: OverlayPanel;

functionCalledWhenYouWantToDisplayOverlayPanel() {
    this.yourService.getDataFromAPI().subscribe((data) => {
        this.data = data;
        this.overlayPanel.show();
    });
}
```

HTML :

```
<p-overlayPanel appendTo="body">
    {{ data }}
</p-overlayPanel>
```